# Looking for a closed form of $\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(N-\int_{0}^{N}e^{xe^{-x}}\mathrm dx\right)?$

Tags: integration, limits

$$\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(N-\int_{0}^{N}e^{xe^{-x}}\mathrm dx\right)=-1.13839 ...\tag1$$

$(1)$ seems to converge to $1.13839...$

**Is there a closed form for this number which is expressable in term of constants?**

$u=xe^{-x}$ then, $$dx={du\over e^{-x}-xe^{-x}}$$

$$\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(N-\int_{0}^{N}{e^{u}\over e^{-x}-u}\mathrm du\right)\tag2$$

Comment: What makes you think it might be expressed in terms of other constants?

Comment: I am just assuming it could be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(1-e^{xe^{-x}}\right)\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto -\log u}{=} \int_{0}^{1}\left(1-e^{-u\log u}\right)\,\frac{du}{u}$$
equals:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}\int_{0}^{1} u^{n-1}\left(\log u\right)^n\,du = \color{red}{-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}}$$
which is a (fast-convergent) series similar to the one appearing in the classical Sophomore's dream.

Comment: Does this sum has a closed form?

Comment: @123: you may call it $C_{123}$, if you like :D Jokes apart, it is a trascendental number for sure. I am not aware of any algebraic relation between Sophomore's dream constant and "the usual" mathematical constants; my bet is that the same applies here.

Comment: Great answer, @Jack. The OEIS digits of the constant are here: https://oeis.org/A135608

Comment: Thank you, always give the best answer.